# Change Origin of Coordinates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates

How can I possibly change Javascript's origin?  For example, if I were to call offsetTop on a div, it's really tell me how far it is from the origin.  Javascript's origin is at the top left of the page, but how can I move that?

I want to make it at the bottom left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information about `offsetTop` is incorrect. From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop):

> **offsetTop** returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/OffsetParent) node.

You cannot "move" the origin in the way you are thinking, though you could use a bit of math to compute the distance from the element's top edge to the bottom of the screen/page. Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (for clarity, so the code isn't mucked up with cross-browser feature detection):

```
var $doc = $(document),
    docHeight = $doc.height(),
    $elt = $('#some-element-id'),
    top = $elt.offset().top,

    // this is the value you're interested in
    originShiftedTop = docHeight - top;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9KGKv/). Try re-running the fiddle with different `Result` pane heights.

---

Note that jQuery's [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) returns the position of the element relative to the **document**, unlike [`element.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop) the DOM-standard property. jQuery's [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position) function behaves like `element.offsetTop`.